# err TypeError: values.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find post by id and add comment to it .

I'm using postgreSQL.

Here is my model

```
   const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../../config/database')

const Posts =db.define("Topics",{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    title : {
        type : Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    description : {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    username : {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    comment : {
        type:Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
        defaultValue : [],
        allowNull: false
    }

})
module.exports = Posts;
```

Here is my nodeJS Request.

```
    app.put('/addComment/:id', (req, res) => {
    Posts.update({
            comment: req.body.comment
        },
        {
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        }).then((post) => {
        res.send(post)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });
})
```

I'm testing my server using postman but whenever i try to send updated data to the databse I'm always getting this error `err TypeError: values.map is not a function`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this please?
Also in my DB datatype for comment array is `text[]`
I also tried to change `update` to `create` but with no results

Comment: what is the content type of your request? and can you log req.body.comment, please?

Comment: req.body is working correctly i already did that,I also fixed this issue by changing req.body.comment to the [req.body.comment]

Comment: very well, so please post your answer for people with the same issue

Answer (score 3):

you have defined comment in the model of type Array of strings but while update you are directly passing the single string please pass in the array format

```
Posts.update({
        comment: [req.body.comment]   // note the square brackets for array
    },
    {
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }).then((post) => {
    res.send(post)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("err", err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by changing `req.body.comment` to the `[req.body.comment]`.

Answer (score 1):

check your req.body.comment and sent it as array

```
req.body.comment = ['test']
```

Answer (score 0):

you need parsing `req.body.comment` data into Array use `JSON.parse()`

example:

`JSON.parse(req.body.comment)`

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse